# execute command as root and then switch back to user in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a shell script that is started by a specific user, this user is not and cannot be in /etc/sudoers.

Inside the script there is just 1 cp command that needs to run as root, then I need to switch back to the user who originally ran the script.

is this possible? I have tried a few combinations of sudo -i, su -c, etc, etc all of them have failed, any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why can't the user be in the sudoers file?  You can specify the user is able to use sudo for only one specific command/script if you want to restrict their access.  This is essentially no different than what you are trying to do anyway.  Except it's probably safer than what you are trying to do.

Comment: does the user know the root password?

Comment: Why does `cp` need to run as root?  Restrictions on source? Restrictions on destination?  Can the user be in a _group_ with appropriate access?  Please update the post with more detail (rather than responding in comments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer; it can't be done, and for *good* reason! If that were so, than *anyone* could become root. Think about it. :)

HTH

Comment: Thank you @somebody, Appreciate the answer

Comment: You're very welcomed. Do know I wasn't trying to pick on you. Just trying to point out why you shouldn't try to do that. :)